# Android Webview how do you set it to be 100% zoomed in?

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm using Anddown to convert some markdown text to html and I want to display the html in a webview. The webview is part of a fragment that takes up around half the screen on a tablet in landscape.

I want the html to appear at 'normal' scale, as in I never want it zoomed out so you can see the whole page. Most of the time this is fine since text in

blocks wraps when it reaches the end of the view. But some of the markdown elements result in an html element which stretches the view horizontally, so I've got something that looks like this:

```
----
----
----
--------------
----
```

(imagine the dashes are text, the short lines are wrapping correctly to the fragment width)
When I load that to the webview, the page is zoomed out fully so that that long horizontal line fits the width of my view. I don't want this, I want the webview to always be zoomed in. The weird thing is that sometimes when I load the html to the webview, it will automatically zoom in to what I want (but with some horizontal overflow). This doesn't happen every time and when it does, I can see the zoomed out version for a split second before it resizes.

So my question is, how do I get it to default to 'zoomed in' always? I don't care if it means there's some horizontal overflow, I just want the text to be 100% in scale (if that even makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

For normal scale you should use this viewport tag (on your html's header):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">
```

Now, if you want different scale you can change these settings (for example use a scale of 2)

Hope that answers your qauestion

Answer (score 0):

If you're using text.
Have you tried using

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

So the text won't be outside it's parent